# Unable to render Backbone Model default attribute in Underscore template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have set a default Model boolean that I would like to use in an `Underscore` template. When I log the model out in my `initialize` method I see the default but when it tries to render the template underscore returns an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`. Can anyone advise where I may be going wrong with this?

**JS**

```
var PersonModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        'delete': false
    }
});
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: _.template( $('.js-template').html() ),

    initialize: function() {
        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) ); 

        return this;
    }
});

// Setup
var personModel = new PersonModel(data, {parse:true});
var personView = new PersonView({
    model: personModel
});

// Add to DOM
$('.js-ctn').html(personView.render().el);
```

**Template**

```
<script type="text/template" class="js-template">
    <h1>Hey, <%= name %></h1>
    <p><%= delete %></p>
    <button class="js-reset">Reset</button>
</script>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/kw96kLdt/

Comment: I suspect it's because `delete` is a reserved word. Can you try another property name?

Comment: Ah that's it! Totally forgot about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete` is a JavaScript [reserved word](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/reserved-keywords), so you can't use it as an identifier. Change the attribute name and your code will work as expected.